# Postgresql pg_profile getting error while creating snapshot

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

I am referring `https://github.com/zubkov-andrei/pg_profile` for generating awr like report.

Steps which I have followed are as below :

1) Enabled below parameters inside postgresql.conf `(located inside D:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.6\data)`

```
track_activities = on
track_counts = on
track_io_timing = on
track_functions = on

shared_preload_libraries = 'pg_stat_statements'
pg_stat_statements.max = 1000
pg_stat_statements.track = 'top'
pg_stat_statements.save = off

pg_profile.topn = 20
pg_profile.retention = 7
```

2) Manually copied all the file beginning with `pg_profile` to `D:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.6\share\extension`

3) From pgAdmin4 console executed below commands successfully

```
CREATE EXTENSION dblink;
CREATE EXTENSION pg_stat_statements;
CREATE EXTENSION pg_profile;
```

4) To see which node is already present I executed `SELECT * from node_show();`
which resulted in

```
node_name as local
connstr as dbname=postgres port=5432
enabled as true
```

5) To create a snapshot I executed `SELECT * from snapshot('local');`
but getting below error

```
ERROR:  could not establish connection
DETAIL:  fe_sendauth: no password supplied

CONTEXT:  SQL statement "SELECT dblink_connect('node_connection',node_connstr)"
PL/pgSQL function snapshot(integer) line 38 at PERFORM
PL/pgSQL function snapshot(name) line 9 at RETURN
SQL state: 08001
```

Once I am able to generate multiple snapshot then I guess I should be able to generate report.

Answer (score 0):

just use SELECT * from snapshot()

look at the code of the function. It calls the other one with node as parameter.